# Java: Split String with Regex without deleting delimiters

Tags: java, regex

I have a string that looks like:

```
Hi, <name> pls visit <url>
```

Now i would like to split the string into an array with a regex.

I have tried this:

```
hi.split("(?=<[A-Za-z]+>)");
Output: [Hi, , <name> pls visit , <url>]
```

But i would like to have

```
[Hi, , <name> , pls visit , <url>]
```

Is there a chance to do that ?

Comment: why there is an extra empty item after `Hi,`

Comment: Because the example is `Hi, ....`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String s="Hi, <name> pls visit <url>";
String[] ss = s.split("(?<=> )|(?=<)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ss));
```

the above codes output:

```
[Hi, , <name> , pls visit , <url>]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
String str="Hi, <name> pls visit <url>";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str.split("(?=<)|(?<=> )")));
```

output:

```
[Hi, , <name> , pls visit , <url>]
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/oE7rZ9/5)

---

```
(?=<)|(?<=> )
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/XO8Vu6lMwiXbdG4A)

---

Pattern explanation:

```
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
    <                        '<'
  )                        end of look-ahead
 |                        OR
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
    >                        '> '
  )                        end of look-behind
```

Comment: he wanted `<name>(space)`

Comment: how did you get the shared link from reg101? must be registered user or what? I cannot find that feature.

Comment: @Kent regex101 is free for everyone. Just click on `save regex` link. Are you not getting it?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think that "save regex" will do that. :-), I kept looking for "share regex" or "perm link" sth. like that.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using lookahead, I believe the Java-flavor of regex has lookbehind as well. So something like:

```
hi.split("(?=<[A-Za-z_]\\w*>)|(?<=<[A-Za-z_]\\w*>)");
```

(note: I changed it to `[A-Za-z_]\w*` so <_this3> would also match but <5thing> would not)