# Split String but not removing delimiter

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a example String: `abcd $cvzasd$ waedqwe$qewrerw$dsaxcz $dasdasd$ $fowjew$ dsadsa`. The $ sign is my delimiter. And I want split this String, but not removing delimiter $. I want at result list with following 8 elements:

```
abcd, $cvzasd$, waedqwe, $qewrerw$, waedqwe, dsaxcz, $dasdasd$, $fowjew$, dsadsa
```

How I can't get that result? It's possible, create regex for that? I found a good example: [Java: Split String with Regex without deleting delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25427711/java-split-string-with-regex-without-deleting-delimiters) but this not satisfy me because in example use delimiters < and > and it works only for different delimiter.

Otherwise I found a solution with replace my sign by adding to my sign additional sign. Example replace $ by -$ and split by -. But I think is not good solution for me.

Comment: that looks more like a whitespace is the delimiter. Why would cvzasd have a $ on both sides?

Comment: I'm also confused by how you are splitting by '$'. In some cases you are splitting before and other cases afterward. You also have two '$' in a row, which would produce an empty element.

Comment: It really looks like you need to split with `\\s+`, see http://ideone.com/qltEjq. Are you sure of the expected output?

Comment: Sorry. I I chose the wrong example. The $ must be my delimiter, because then I replace the word between $ and I must know, which word is between $ signs. I edited first post.

Comment: How do you determine which words are between dollar signs and which ones are not? `waedqwe$qewrerw$dsaxcz$waedqwe$qewrerw$dsaxcz$` Who should get them in a string like this?

Comment: Your example is still very bad because the first match should either be `abcd ` or `abcd $` but not just `abcd`. You should firstly get VERY clear on what the exact outcome should be and why - Java will not do what you *think*, it will do what you tell it to do. Right know even the other humans here do not understand what you want - Java will have even more trouble ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the constrained-width lookbehind supported by Java regex engine (the `{0,100}` limited quantifier is allowed in Java lookbehinds, just make sure you adjust the value in case you have longer values):

```
\s+|(?=(?<!\$\w{0,100})(?<!\s)\$)|(?<=\$(?!\w{0,100}\$))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs%2b%7c(%3f%3d(%3f%3c!%5c%24%5cw%7b0%2c100%7d)(%3f%3c!%5cs)%5c%24)%7c(%3f%3c%3d%5c%24(%3f!%5cw%7b0%2c100%7d%5c%24))&i=abcd+%24cvzasd%24+waedqwe%24qewrerw%24dsaxcz+%24dasdasd%24+%24fowjew%24+dsadsa)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/QBxZth):

```
String pat = "\\s+|(?=(?<!\\$\\w{0,100})(?<!\\s)\\$)|(?<=\\$(?!\\w{0,100}\\$))";
String s = "abcd $cvzasd$ waedqwe$qewrerw$dsaxcz $dasdasd$ $fowjew$ dsadsa";
String[] res = s.split(pat);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
// => [abcd, $cvzasd$, waedqwe, $qewrerw$, dsaxcz, $dasdasd$, $fowjew$, dsadsa]
```

Comment: Your example output doesn't group $<term>$ in half the cases:
`abcd $cvzasd$ waedqwe $qewrerw $dsaxcz $dasdasd$ $fowjew$ dsadsa`

Comment: Results: [abcd, $cvzasd$, waedqwe, $qewrerw, $dsaxcz, $dasdasd$, $fowjew$, dsadsa]

Comment: Now, the results are as expected. @Grayson

Answer (score -1):

Like luk2302 says, you can use a whitespace as a delimiter which separates an item in the list from another:

```
public class SplitEx {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "abcd $cvzasd$ waedqwe $dasdasd$ $fowjew$ dsadsa";
        String[] parts = s.split("\\s+"); // note: returns an array
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
    }
}
```

prints:

```
[abcd, $cvzasd$, waedqwe, $dasdasd$, $fowjew$, dsadsa]
```

Comment: this will not work for the OP's original string containing "waedqwe$qewrerw$dsaxcz"   Note that unlike your example there are no spaces here, but the OP wants this to resolve to "waedqwe, $qewrerw$, dsaxcz"

Comment: It is still not clear if the original string does _not_ have spaces and the confusion is not only mine.